# Definition of the approximation property of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space.

On [page 59 of *Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ECSUvWFxJykC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22approximation+property+if%22+%22defant%22&source=bl&ots=p8trtsnx9_&sig=NNSdS6C1ndP8WQUyR3Dk8m7sa44&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRi9_0o_nYAhWJPFAKHcgECPIQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22approximation%20property%20if%22%20%22defant%22&f=false) the authors define that $E$ has the *approximation property*, if for every absolutely convex compact subset $K$ of $E$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is a bounded linear operator $T:E\to E$ of finite rank with $\left\|Tx-x\right\|\le\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$.

On the other hand, on [page 72 of *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces](https://books.google.de/books?id=MSLUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Proposition+4.1.+The+following+are+equivalent+for+a+Banach+space&source=bl&ots=HZdDfNVtER&sig=cFKsn2femwL3U5D_G-X-ZHCd8zg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBlpLRpPnYAhVCElAKHd9fC40Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=Proposition%204.1.%20The%20following%20are%20equivalent%20for%20a%20Banach%20space&f=false), the author defines that a complete $E$ (i.e. a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $E$) has the approximation property, if the condition above is satisfied for every compact subset $K$ of $E$. Hence, he doesn't require $K$ to be absolutely convex.

I have almost no knowledge in this topic. I just want to understand, if both definitions are equivalent in the case of a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $E$. Are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two properties are equivalent in Banach spaces. Clearly the second implies the first, since the family of absolutely convex compact sets in $E$ is contained in the family of compact sets.

Let's call $M \subset E$ "good" if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a continuous finite-rank operator $T \colon E \to E$ with $\lVert Tx - x\rVert \leqslant \epsilon$ for all $x\in M$. It is straightforward that every subset of a good set is good, so to see that the first property implies the second in Banach spaces it suffices to see that every compact subset of a Banach space is contained in an absolutely convex compact set.

The absolutely convex hull of a totally bounded set is totally bounded in locally convex spaces (for the convex hull, this is part (b) of theorem 3.20 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, the modification for the absolutely convex hull is easy), and hence the closure of the absolutely convex hull of a compact set is an absolutely convex compact set in Banach spaces.